# CCMenuItem that added as a child to another CCMenuItem doesn't respond to touch

Tags: c#, xna, decorator, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-for-xna

I'm implementing a decorator pattern for adding the selected/unselected events to `CCMenuItem` inheritors:

```
  public class MenuItemDecorator : CCMenuItem
  {
    public event EventHandler OnSelected;
    public event EventHandler OnUnselected;
    private readonly CCMenuItem _menuItem;

    public MenuItemDecorator(CCMenuItem menuItem) //set a decorated item
    {
      menuItem.ThrowIfNull("menuItem");

      _menuItem = menuItem;
      AddChild(_menuItem);
    }

    public override void Selected()
    {
      base.Selected();
      _menuItem.Selected();

      if(OnSelected != null)
        OnSelected(this, null);
    }

    public override void Unselected()
    {
      base.Unselected();
      _menuItem.Unselected();

      if(OnUnselected != null)
        OnUnselected(this, null);
    }
  }
```

Then I "decorate" my items:

```
...
var soundToggle = MenuItemToggleBuilder.New(soundOffBtn, soundOnBtn)
                                       .SetPosition(positionX, positionY)
                                       .SetTarget(ToggleSelector)
                                       .Build();

var decorToggle = new MenuItemDecorator(soundToggle);
decorToggle.SetTarget(Selector); // for debugging
decorToggle.OnSelected += (s, e) => toggleWafer.Scale = 0.95f;
decorToggle.OnUnselected += (s, e) => toggleWafer.Scale = 1f;

LayerMenu.AddChild(soundToggle, int.MaxValue); //LayerMenu is CCMenu
...

private void Selector(object o)
{//breakpoint is here
}
...
```

But when I start the application and click on my `decorToggle` it doesn't respond. 
Moreover it doesn't step into my `Selector` method (where I've set the breakpoint).

So what I'm doing wrong? Could it be made easier? Thanks in advance

---

Thank you, @LearnCocos2D. But why debugger doesn't stop on breakpoint in `Selector` method?

Also what with the second part of question? Could I add custom behavior to `Selected/Unselected` events on `CCMenuItem` inheritors without inheritance from a concrete `CCMenuItem` inheritor(sorry for the pun) and overriding the `Selected/Unselected` methods?

i.e. `CCMenuItemImageWithExtendedSelect`, `CCMenuItemLabelWithExtendedSelect`, `CCMenuItemToggleWithExtendedSelect` etc. and each of these classes just overriding `Selected/Unselected` methods (as in my `MenuItemDecorator`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If CCMenu has the same behavior as in cocos2d-iphone, which is safe to assume, then CCMenuItem are not stackable. You can't have a CCMenuItem as child of another menu item and both reacting to touches properly.

Comment: This is because it is actually CCMenu that receives the touch and decides which of its children (CCMenuItems) was touched. If an CCMenuItem were to be stacked on another, the CCMenu would not be aware of it (it wouldn't be added to its children).